# MS-Project: any ideas on how to approach defining a MINIMUM work assignment per day for resources?

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning, workload

I am currently working on a high level project plan with all our department's projects and resources allocated to each project (roughly like 10% during 2 months, 20% during 2 weeks, etc.). This is to get a rough idea about (over)allocations and free capacities.

In our team it's the culture to ALWAYS make an **assignment of any team resources** for a **MINIMUM of 0.5 person-days (4 hours)**. Everything below this would be too much micromanagement - and especially on my high level project plan, this would be far too detailed.

What I basically have is 1 Task for each ongoing Project. Those "Tasks" are defined as:

- Fixed Duration
- Constrain: start no earlier than DATE XY (each Project's start date)
- Duration: eg. 2 months
- Effort driven: NO

To these Projects I assign the according resources with a percentage or work amount. Example:

- Project A (Duration: 2 Months, fixed duration)
  -- Resource A: 80% (= 4 person-days/week)
  -- Resource B: 20% (= 1 person-days/week)
  -- Resource C: 10% (= 0.5 person-days/week)

So this works fine, Project is automatically calculating the work hours and dividing it based on the task's duration time. But this also means that I end up with stuff like:

- Resource A: *7.24* hours/day
- Resource B: *0.82* hours/day
- Resource C: *0.12* hours/day

This is bascially useless for me, because our People just do *not work less than 0.5 person-days on a day*. So I'd rather have "Resource B" work 1 full day or 2 half-days per week, than a little bit every day during a week. I feel like MS Project is pushing me into micromanagement of my resources...

**Is it possible to define this kind of calculation-rule in MS Project? Something like telling Project "do not assign a resource less than 4 hours per day"?**

Thanks for any inputs and possible solutions! It might be that I am approaching this wrongly :)
~ Oliver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not be terribly concerned about the math Project is doing.  Project has to spread the work per hour based upon the assignment unit.  I would present the information to your users on a weekly basis.  If they work 8 hours in one day, record it as such.

The only other option is to manually edit the spread of the work in the Task Usage view.  Enter the 4 hours of work on a specific day - but it sounds like too much detail for me.

Comment: Thank you @JulieS , I support your recommendation on presenting the data on a weekly basis (or even monthly). Seems to be the most efficient approach to achieve the final goal.

Comment: You're welcome and thank you for the feedback.